# Identifying the sequence from the set of points given?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, graphing-functions

Let us consider two sequences
$a_{n} = \frac{c^{2n}}{2n}$ and $b_{n} = c^{2n}$, $n \in \Bbb{N}$ then
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \rightarrow c^{2}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$
and
$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} \rightarrow c^{2}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

So if we plot $n$ vs $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$, then it should converge to the value $c^2$ (similar with $b_{n}$).

We see that both sequences converge to the same value, so how to distinguish between those two sequences if we don't know a prior about $a_{n}, b_{n}$? $c$ is some positive quantity less than $1$

any idea?

If we reframe it: given two sets of data points $P$ and $Q$, how to tell which data follows which sequence? any graphical method?

Comment: $b_n>a_n$ for all $n$ ... is that not enough? Alternately, compute $a_n/b_n$ and see if it acts more like $1/n$ or $n$.

Comment: Yeah, let me edit my question that we do not know about which pattern the data points follow..so we don't know whether it follows a particular kind of sequence

Comment: Yup now we don't know apriori which sequence we have at hand..we only have data points

Comment: +1 interesting question (which I am clueless about).  Nice presentation.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking. What are the "data points" $P$ and $Q$ you are given, and what is their relationship to the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: We cannot use the ratio criterion just shown in the question above to distinguish between two sequences numerically as they are converging to the same constant...suppose now there are two sets of data points $P, Q$ which also are such that their ratio of consecutive elements converge to the same constant, then how to identify what sequence $P$ follows and what sequence $Q$ follows? there is no relationship of $a_{n}, b_{n}$ with $P, Q$. I just used the examples of $a_{n}, b_{n}$ to show that the trio of consecutive method fails and needs some other approach.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine a sequence from its limit?

Comment: yeah, kind of! even gets trickier if both sequences converge to the same limit

Answer (score 1):

You have candidate functional forms, so fit them using a regression.  For example, suppose your data set is $\{2.03, 2.06045, 2.78848, 4.24545, 6.89462\}$.  The best-fit exponential is $$b_n=0.972149e^{0.385244 x}$$ which has the wrong constant prefactor and still has a residual of $\approx0.2$ at $n=5$.  But it matches $$a_n=\frac{2.03^n}{n}$$ perfectly, because that's how I concocted the numbers in the first place.